# Scheme: Find all elements of a list greater than X number

Tags: scheme

How do I turn this:

```
(filter (lambda (x) (and (number? x) (> x 2)))
        '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))

=> (3 4 5 6 7)
```

Into a define function in Scheme where I can pass in the list and conditional number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by *passing the list and the number* as parameters:

```
(define (filter-greater lst num)
  (filter (lambda (x) (and (number? x) (> x num)))
          lst))
```

Comment: I guess I was having trouble calling it, why doesn't this work?:
(filter-greater '((1 2 3 4) (2))) , it prints this => () . Sorry, I know this question is pretty stupid I'm just stuck

Comment: Because you have _too many brackets_. The correct way to call the procedure would be: `(filter-greater '(1 2 3 4) 2)`